# How to provide view controllers with pointer to already-initialized singleton object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

After initializing a Singleton object via `-[AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?]`, how does one pass the pointer of this object to a view controller?

It it helps, let's assume that the object is stand-alone but reasonably coupled with the UI.  (For example, managing a server connection thread.)  So I would prefer something more "intimate" than signaling via `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: If it's around for the lifetime of the program, I'd suggest `AppDelegate` so that it doesn't disappear if you refactor your VCs

Comment: I have rewritten my question to request a fact based answer.  I was stuck for quite awhile trying to figure out how to reach back to a singleton object from `-[AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]`.  And now I have the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

If the object is needed by a single view controller, initialize it in `viewDidLoad`.  If it is is needed by the entire app, initialize it in the app delegate.

In your case, it is probably best in the app delegate since it is needed for the lifetime of the application and is not just used for one view controller.

You can create a property in your app delegate and put your object in it.  You can get the delegate from anywhere in the application like this:

```
((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

so, as long as you have #imported AppDelegate.h in the file you are accessing the app delegate from, then you can get the object like this:

```
MyObject *object = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).propertyName;
```

Comment: Thanks @NobodyNada.  If I do it within AppDelegate, is there a generally accepted way to communicate this pointer to viewController?  That's how I got here!  (I have a sinking feeling that I am re-opening a Singleton debate here.)

Comment: You can creates a property in your app delegate and access it from the view controller like this: `((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).propertyName`.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!  (I was also looking for confirmation that `viewDidLoad` or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` were the right two places.)  I had to revise my question to request a fact-based answer.  If you can retouch this I will point to it as the answer.

Comment: What exactly do you want me to change?

Answer (score 2):

Does it seem like you need singleton object!? Sounds like yes and you shouldn't care about "where to initialize it". You just create shared instance and it will be created right after first invocation:

> [[myObjectWhichLivesForever instance] doSomething]

If you need some UI features in it, you should design it to be flexible... f.e if you want progress bar to be displayed in `myView` of `MyUIViewController`:

```
[[MyObjectWhichLivesForever instance] showProgressBarInView:myView]
```

or even class methods:

```
[MyObjectWhichLivesForever showProgressBarInView:myView]
```

I believe `MBProgressHud` and other such things work like this.

Positives:

- object is available all over the application, you don't have to pass pointer from `appDelegate` (it could be painful)

Negatives:

- In the internet lot of information according to why `singleton` is not a best solution (but it is met often in development and in particular for iOS)